# Is dropping multiple tables from an sqlite3 database possible?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I was trying to drop multiple tables from a database with the syntax: `

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B,C,A;
```

But this produces a syntax error.
A comment mentioned enclosing names within backticks, that didn't work either.
`

```
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `meta`,`urls`;")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

`

Comment: Refresh your memory with https://sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html

Comment: @Shawn I'm not sure if I'm missing anything. But the documentation doesn't mention anything about dropping multiple tables.

Comment: Exactly. You're getting a syntax error because what you're trying isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Got it, I had assumed that dropping multiple tables must be a common use case. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to issue a drop statement for each table.